# How to get location of matched tokens using pyparsing?

Tags: python, pyparsing

So far I have tried using 'setParseAction' to get the location of matched tokens, but it doesn't work as I expect sometimes. Take this code as an example:

```
>>> from pyparsing import *
>>> 
>>> Z = Literal('0')
>>> POINT = Literal('.')
>>> BIN_DIGITS = Word('01')
>>> OCT_DIGITS = Word('01234567')
>>> DEC_DIGITS = Word('0123456789')
>>> HEX_DIGITS = Word('0123456789abcdefABCDEF')
>>> DEC_INT = DEC_DIGITS.setParseAction(lambda t: int(t[0]))
>>> BIN_INT = Combine(Z + ((Literal('b') | 'B')) + BIN_DIGITS).\
...         setParseAction(lambda t: int(t[0], 2))
>>> OCT_INT = Combine(Z + ((Literal('o') | 'O')) + OCT_DIGITS).\
...         setParseAction(lambda t: int(t[0], 8))
>>> HEX_INT = Combine(Z + ((Literal('x') | 'X')) + HEX_DIGITS).\
...         setParseAction(lambda t: int(t[0], 16))
>>> INTEGER = HEX_INT | OCT_INT | BIN_INT | DEC_INT
>>> EXP = Combine(CaselessLiteral('E') + Optional(Literal('+') | '-') + DEC_INT)
>>> POINT_FLOAT = Combine(Optional(DEC_INT) + POINT + DEC_INT) | \
...         Combine(DEC_INT + POINT)
>>> EXP_FLOAT = Combine(DEC_INT + EXP) | Combine(POINT_FLOAT + EXP)
>>> FLOAT = (EXP_FLOAT | POINT_FLOAT).setParseAction(lambda t: float(t[0]))
>>> 
>>> 
>>> def p(s, l, t):
...     print 'Location of %s:  %s' % (t[0], l,)
... 
>>> 
>>> NUMBER = (FLOAT | INTEGER).setParseAction(p)
>>> NUMBER.parseString('    12345')
Location of 12345:  0
([12345], {})
>>> NUMBER.parseString(' 12345')
Location of 12345:  0
([12345], {})
>>> NUMBER.parseString('12345')
Location of 12345:  0
([12345], {})
```

Location is always 0 no matter where I position the number '12345' in the string. However if I try:

```
>>> LITERAL = Literal('someword').setParseAction(p)
>>> LITERAL.parseString('    someword')
Location of someword:  4
(['someword'], {})
>>> LITERAL.parseString(' someword')
Location of someword:  1
(['someword'], {})
>>> LITERAL.parseString('someword')
Location of someword:  0
(['someword'], {})
```

It works as expected. What am I doing wrong in the first example?

Comment: What happens if you do `INTEGER.addParseAction(p).parseString('   12345')`?  I think you are running into the default whitespace skipping that happens in pyparsing.  Depending on what level your parse action is attached in the grammar, the location might fall before or after the leading whitespace has been skipped.  Why are you capturing the location anyway?  If it is to do replacement of text fields using string slicing by location, see if transformString would be a better API method to use.

Comment: I'm implementing a language with a python-like syntax(indented grammar), and I want its multiline string literals to behave like it is described here http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0295/ . For that I'm using a parse action that will split the multiline string in lines, and for each line remove the leading whitespaces up to the column where the string literal starts before joining the lines back. For that I need to have the location where the token is matched(so I can call the 'col' function). Can you link to this transform example?

Comment: Apparently, this only happens when the token to be matches is the first in the input stream

Comment: Yes, because matching `A | B | C` is actually matching `Or([A,B,C])`, and the Or will skip leading whitespace before matching A or B or C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to Paul's tip, I managed work around this problem by combining the 'Or' expression with a supressed whitespace expression, and using it to parse the string. Heres the end result:

```
>>> from pyparsing import *
>>> 
>>> def p(s,l,t):
...     print 'Location of %s: %s' % (s, l,)
... 
>>> Z = Literal('0')
>>> POINT = Literal('.')
>>> BIN_DIGITS = Word('01')
>>> OCT_DIGITS = Word('01234567')
>>> DEC_DIGITS = Word('0123456789')
>>> HEX_DIGITS = Word('0123456789abcdefABCDEF')
>>> DEC_INT = DEC_DIGITS.copy().setParseAction(lambda t: int(t[0]))
>>> BIN_INT = Combine(Z + ((Literal('b') | 'B')) + BIN_DIGITS).\
...         setParseAction(lambda t: int(t[0], 2))
>>> OCT_INT = Combine(Z + ((Literal('o') | 'O')) + OCT_DIGITS).\
...         setParseAction(lambda t: int(t[0], 8))
>>> HEX_INT = Combine(Z + ((Literal('x') | 'X')) + HEX_DIGITS).\
...         setParseAction(lambda t: int(t[0], 16))
>>> INTEGER = HEX_INT | OCT_INT | BIN_INT | DEC_INT
>>> EXP = Combine(CaselessLiteral('E') + Optional(Literal('+') | Literal('-')) + DEC_DIGITS)
>>> POINT_FLOAT = Combine(Optional(DEC_DIGITS) + POINT + DEC_DIGITS) | \
...         Combine(DEC_DIGITS + POINT)
>>> EXP_FLOAT = Combine(DEC_DIGITS + EXP) | Combine(POINT_FLOAT + EXP)
>>> FLOAT = (EXP_FLOAT | POINT_FLOAT).setParseAction(lambda t: float(t[0]))
>>> NUMBER = (FLOAT | INTEGER).setParseAction(p)
>>> NUMBER2 = Combine(ZeroOrMore(White(exact=1)).suppress() + NUMBER)
>>> 
>>> NUMBER2.parseString('    12345')
Location of     12345: 4
(['12345'], {})
```